# MySql not null composite fields

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is possible in MySql table creation, but this is my scenario:

I have a table 'company' which has many fields, two of which are: 'sector_id' and 'sector_other_id'

I have two other tables: 'sector' and 'sectorOther'

'sector' has two fields: 'id' and 'name'
'sectorOther' has same two fields: 'id' and 'name'

'sector' has twenty or so sectors such as "entertainment", "technology", etc...
'sectorOther' is a table that exists to contain other sector names that users using my app can input via a text box when entries in the 'sector' table do not sufficiently define the sector for their particular company.

In the 'company' table, 'sector_id' is a FK which references 'id' in the 'sector' table
and 'sector_other_id' is a FK which references 'id' in the 'sector_other' table.

So here's what I want to achieve: I want some kind of constraint on the 'company' table so that when a record is entered into the 'company' table, one value must be entered into either the 'sector_id' column or the 'sector_other_id' column, BUT only one value can be entered between the two fields. i.e.: you can't enter a value into both 'sector_id' AND 'sector_other_id'.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If redesign is not an option, the only way you can enforce desired restriction with mysql (still no `CHECK` constraints as far as I know) is to write `before insert` and `before update` triggers that throws error if those 2 fields are both not null...

**Update.** 
You can refactor your tables to use 'common parent' for `sector` and `other_sector` tables thus eliminating the need for exclusive arcs in `company` (and maybe other tables).

Briefly, you create a new table, for instance 
`abstract_sector(abstract_sector_id, abstract_sector_type[enum, either 'sector' or 'other_sector'])`. 
Then make old tables details of this table :
`sector(abstract_sector_id,abstract_sector_type [enum,always 'other sector']....);

other_sector(abstract_sector_id,abstract_sector_type[enum,always 'other other_sector'],...);`

Now `company` doesn't need 2 fields, but just one (`abstract_sector_id`). 
Note about `abstract_sector_type`. The field seems to be redundant because `abstract_sector_id` is unique itself, the reason for type field is to enforce that particular abstract sector is stored exactly in 1 table (either `sector` or `other_sector`; never in both). You can omit this field if you are ok to leave this logic up to application.

Comment: Well actually, I haven't created the database or tables yet. I have the design down on paper. All tables and relations look fine except for 'sector' part of it. The design is as follows:

Comment: cont... a 'sector_other' table. 'sector' table will contain pre-defined sector names, whereas 'sector_other' exists so that when a member types in a new sector in the "other" txtbox in the app, it will be stored in the 'sector_other' table. So in the 'memberCompany' table, there are 2 fields: 'sector_id' and 'sector_other_id'. Only one of these fields can have a value for a record, but there must be one. i.e.: a members' company must define it's sector, but it can only be one sector, either from the 'sector' table or the 'sector_other' table. I know it's not perfect design. any suggestion?

Comment: My first comment above got truncated somehow. So anyway, there's a 'memberCompany'. each company has to define it's sector. member can pick from a pre-defined list of sectore, or enter a sector through a txtbox in the app. if they do the latter, i have to store that somewhere, so I'm thinking to create a 'sector_other' table for this purpose. See my previous comment for rest of design description...

Comment: @user2489551 : Check updated answer with redesign suggestions

Comment: thanks for the advice. I guess there's a couple of ways this could be implemented in the table design. I ended up making just one table: 'sector', with 3 fields: 'id', 'sector_type(enum: 'sector', 'sector_other')', 'name'. So I used your idea of using an enum, but only to distinguish between standard sectors added by admin and sectors added by users of the app. Of course there'll be further business logic in the app itself to deal with user inputted sectors names but that's another story. thanks for the enum suggestion though; that definitely helped me.